# How to color grep output

Tags: linux, bash

When I type

```
memcached -vv 2>&1 | grep --color=always "SET\|GET"
```

I get nice memcached stats

> GET AR-City-1
>
> GET rest-part-241
>
> SET rest-part-241 Value len is 685
>
> GET main-rest-list-1

It would be great to pipe this to something, and color `GET` in green instead of the default red.

How could I do that?

Comment: Related question from the U&L SE: [How to have tail -f show colored output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8414/1174)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be probably written shorter but solution gives the result:

```
memcached -vv 2>&1 | sed -e "s/^GET.*$/\x1b[31m&\x1b[0m/" | sed -e "s/^SET.*$/\x1b[32m&\x1b[0m/"
```

Or if you wish with background colors instead of foreground color:

```
memcached -vv 2>&1 | sed -e "s/^GET.*$/\x1b[41m&\x1b[0m/" | sed -e "s/^SET.*$/\x1b[42m&\x1b[0m/"
```

So GET is green, SET is red.

Comment: If you want to use `sed` I think you can use `sed` one time and you can skip using of `grep`: `sed -n -r "/SET|GET/ s@SET...@replace_what_you_want@p ; s@GET...@replace_what_you_want@p"

Comment: I worked on this a little, this is solution: 
memcached -vv 2>&1 | sed -e "s/GET.*/\x1b[32m&\x1b[0m/" | sed -e "s/SET.*/\x1b[31m&\x1b[0m/" | grep "GET\|SET" # thx!

Answer (score 4):

for gnu grep this will work:

```
$ export GREP_COLOR="01;32"
```

where "01" means: bold and "32" green. The default is "01:31" (bold red). Other colors:

- 31:red
- 32:green
- 33:yellow
- 34:blue
- 35:purple

These colors may look different depending on how your terminal is configured, but those above are the standard colors.

If

> $ env | grep GREP_COLORS

gives you a result, those settings supersede the GREP_COLOR setting (note the "S"), see the grep manage for more detailed settings using GREP_COLORS.

Comment: thx for the answer, settings works well in a way that default color now is green, but I do not have SET in red and GET in green as sad in question.

Answer (score 1):

try [rpen](https://github.com/rtulke/rpen)  a text highlighter based on egrep :)

Comment: Always try to add more details in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see different words in different colors then use [colorize](http://grip.espace-win.net/doc/apps/monotone/contrib/colorize) for example

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative text colorizer based on ack-grep:

https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter